# create a line break within a div

Tags: html, css

I will have 3 icons side by side that will float left when the window shrinks.  Under each icon, I'd like to add some text.  I can pretty much get it as you can see below.

```css
.icons {
 BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; 
  HEIGHT: 100px; 
  BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; 
  WIDTH: 100px; 
  BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; 
  FLOAT: left; 
  BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">div 1</br><a>some text</a></div>
<div class="icons">div 2</div>
<div class="icons">div 3</div>
```

In jsfiddle, this `</br>` tag seems to come up as invalid.  Is there a valid and / or better way to accomplish this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kp950/mum68pwv/

Comment: Why are you using the anchor (`<a>`) tag in the first place? You can use `span` if you need to. Also `<br />` is the proper syntax, not `</br>`

Comment: It might be because all your CSS is in CAPS.  I know it sounds silly, but that might be it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn No. CSS is case insensitive. You would have a point if there'd been a mismatch between the class name and the selector (as class names are case sensitive), but the OP's CSS is OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just apply `display: block` to your text elements.

```
a { display: block; }
```

The will force each element to consume the full available width of the container, and subsequent elements to the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/mum68pwv/4/

Answer (score 7):

You're getting an error thrown in jsfiddle due to your linebreak syntax being wrong.

You're using `</br>` when you should be using `<br/>`

**2020/HTML5 EDIT**

You no longer need to use self-closing tags in HTML5 (though browsers can still handle them), instead you can simply use `<br>`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `</br>` use `<br>` or `<br />`

`<br />` is a valid tag whereas `</br>` is not so.

Use :

```
<div class="icons">div 1
<br>some text
</div>
<div class="icons">div 2<br>some
<br>some text
</div>
<div class="icons">div 3
<br>some text
</div>
```

P.S.

`<a>` is anchor tag and it is not a good option for adding little elements to your webpage. Instead use [`<span>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) tag which will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `<br>` tag

So this
`<div class="icons">div 1</br><a>some text</a></div>`

should become
`<div class="icons">div 1<br><a>some text</a></div>`